# CSS rule affecting more than just my table

Tags: html, css

I have attempted to make a table on my page scrollable when the browser width reaches a certain point, but my problem is that the CSS rules I implemented are not exclusively affecting the table, but also the images below the table. Can anyone tell me what is happening?

http://www.sunrisehousing.com/node/322

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what is happening?" you mean without seeing the code?

Comment: This is not nearly enough information.

Comment: You need to expand and complete your question so that we can **help you** solve your problem, not **do it for you**. You haven't provided any of the code you've tried and the link you sent does not showcase it either.

Comment: Sorry, I am obviously new to this. However, @CaseyRule gave me the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, very simpley, that your `div.table-container` contains more than just your table.  If you close off that div after your table closing tag, you should see the results you are looking for.

I image that that your double opening table tags

```
<table><table...
```

Are also messing with how the HTML is being parsed.  Given the part of your html that looks like this at the end of the table:

```
</p></table></div></div></div></div></div>


</div></div>

    </div>

                    </div>
```

it looks like your IDE autofill is getting confused....